Probability of boat being in cave 1 given the unsuccessful efforts
The problem is from the linked contest: Yandex Contest.
Problem:
In ancient Egypt, the sun god Ra travels across the sky daily in his sacred boat. Every morning, Ra begins to sail across the sky in a sparkling boat, and in the evening he descends into the underworld. The Egyptians believe that he fights the treacherous god Apop all night, defeats him, and in the morning he sails back into the sky.
God Apop is scary and dangerous; he hunts the boat so that Ra cannot illuminate the lands and darkness reigns in the world. One day, Apop attacked Ra, captured the sacred boat, and hid it in one of his two caves. Ra is looking for his boat, but the sky is covered with clouds, and in the darkness, it is not visible where the boat is. The probability that the boat is in the first cave is 0.65, and the probability of finding the boat is 0.44. Ra has already searched 3 times in the first cave and 7 times in the second cave, but the search was unsuccessful.
Find the probability that the boat is in the first cave, knowing about Ra's unsuccessful attempts to find it. Also, determine the minimum number of attempts by which the number of unsuccessful attempts in the first cave must differ from the number of unsuccessful attempts in the second cave so that the probability from part 1 becomes less than 0.5.
What I tried:
I immediately recognized this as a Bayesian problem. Intuitively, it seems that the more we find that the boat is not in the first cave, the more likely it is that the boat is in the second cave, since it must be in one of the two caves. Similarly, the more we fail to find the boat in the second cave, the more likely it seems that the boat is in the first cave.
Now, what I did was define:

( A ) as the event that the boat is in the first cave.
( B ) as the event of searching 3 times in the first cave and not finding the boat.
( C ) as the event of searching 7 times in the second cave and not finding the boat.

We want to find $P(A \mid B \cap C) $, which by the definition of conditional probability is:
$
P(A \mid B \cap C) = \frac{P(A \cap B \cap C)}{P(B \cap C)}
$
However, I am struggling to compute $ P(B \cap C) $ and $ P(A \cap B \cap C) $. Specifically, I am unsure how to calculate these terms.
Could anyone help me figure out how to find these two probabilities?

Not sure the rules are clear.  Trusting that the boat is actually in cave  $#1$, are the three searches for it independent? That doesn't sound terribly realistic,  so if you want to assume it you should do so explicitly.

Also,  we aren't given the probability of finding it in cave $#2$ given that it is there.  That number is important... if you are sure to find it if it is there, then having searched for it there unsuccessfully proves it is in cave $#1$

@lulu in the official sol they just mentioned answer to be this where a means a unsuccessful searches in boat 1 and b for boat 2 : $
P(a, b) = \frac{0.65(1 - 0.44)^a}{0.65(1 - 0.44)^a + (1 - 0.65)(1 - 0.44)^b}
$  , even i think that searches should be dependent on each outcome

So they appear to be assuming independence AND they are assuming that the same success probability holds for the two caves.  Neither of those seem realistic,  though of course you can assume what you want for a math problem. But you do have to state your assumptions

yes i believe but can you please tell if the bayesian part is fine ? and also helping in evaluating the denominator and numerator parts ?

There are two paths to getting the observed result,  according to which cave it's really in.  The denominator is the sum of the probabilities of those two paths.  The numerator is the probability of the case you are interested in.  Perfectly correct,  if the assumptions are.

i think i can now solve it thanks, just would like to know by same success probability holding for two caves , you mean the probability of finding the boat in cave 1 or 2 remains 0.65 and 0.35 for any number of searches in respective caves?

No. The given data says that if the thing is in cave $#1$ and you search for it,  there is a $.44$ chance of finding it.  It is silent on the parallel situation for cave $#2$ but the official calculation appears to assume it is also $.44$ in that case.

okay thanks now i understood it
